# SubTotal Query in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have a query which I am struggling with.

I'm pulling a list of Purchase Orders and Invoices raised over a period of the current year (along with the budget, Cost Centre, etc.)

The query works just fine in this respect :

```sql
    SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
            dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_PERIOD as PERIOD, 
            dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT.C_CODE AS Nominal, 
                        dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT.C_DESCRIPTION AS Cost_Description, 
            dbo.T_COSTCENTRE.C_DESCRIPTION AS Cost_Centre, 
            format (dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_AMOUNTBASE, 'c', 'en-gb') AS Budget, 
                        format (dbo.ATE_PO_SummedByPeriod.Amount, 'c', 'en-gb') AS Purchase_Orders,
            format (dbo.ATE_InvoicesSummedByPeriod.[Net Amount], 'c', 'en-gb') AS Invoices

FROM                dbo.ATE_PO_SummedByPeriod RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.ATE_InvoicesSummedByPeriod RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET ON dbo.ATE_InvoicesSummedByPeriod.Cost_Centre = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_COSTCENTRE AND 
                        dbo.ATE_InvoicesSummedByPeriod.C_PERIOD = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_PERIOD AND 
                        dbo.ATE_InvoicesSummedByPeriod.Nominal_ID = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C__OWNER_ ON 
                        dbo.ATE_PO_SummedByPeriod.Nominal_ID = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C__OWNER_ AND 
                        dbo.ATE_PO_SummedByPeriod.C_COSTCENTRE = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_COSTCENTRE AND 
                        dbo.ATE_PO_SummedByPeriod.PERIOD = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_PERIOD LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.T_COSTCENTRE ON dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_COSTCENTRE = dbo.T_COSTCENTRE.C_ID RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT LEFT OUTER JOIN
                        dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERGROUP ON dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT.C_GROUP = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERGROUP.C_ID ON 
                        dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C__OWNER_ = dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT.C_ID

WHERE 
    (dbo.ATE_InvoicesSummedByPeriod.[Net Amount] > 0) 
    and
    (dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT.C_CODE) IN ('34120')
    and
    (dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_PERIOD) IN ('202101', '202102', '202103', '202104', '202105', '202106', '202107', '202108', '202109', '202110', '202111', '202112')
ORDER BY PERIOD
```

This returns something like the following :

```
PERIOD  Nominal Cost_Description    Cost_Centre Budget      Purchase_Orders  Invoices
202101  34120   Computer / IT Costs Trailers    £6,543.21   NULL             £1,234.56
202101  34120   Computer / IT Costs Parts       £1,234.56   £6,543.21        £1,234.56
...
```

What I want is (within the same query)

1. A "Total" for Budget, Purchase_Orders and Invoices to appear at the bottom of the table
2. A Total per "PERIOD and Nominal" (so "for Jan, 21.  The running total for budget is £xxxx, the running total for Purchase_Orders is £xxxx and the same for Invoices.
3. And finally......is there a "neater" way of identifying the periods I'm interested in (for example)....

   (dbo.T_GENERALLEDGERACCOUNT_PERIODBUDGET.C_PERIOD) IN ('2021%')

Comment: FYI [3+ part naming on Columns will be Deprecated](https://wp.larnu.uk/3-part-naming-on-columns-will-be-deprecated/). Stick to aliasing your objects and qualifying your columns with that.

Comment: `SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT .. ORDER BY` is a deprecated trick to get ordering in views; recent versions of the optimizer simply ignore these shenanigans entirely and disregard the order. If this is a regular query, just omit the `TOP(100) PERCENT`; if it's intended to go in a view, be aware that it does nothing (or will do nothing some day when you upgrade).

Comment: Thanks both for your reply.  Understand the part of removing the deprecated "TOP(100) PERCENT", so thank you.

Comment: Not sure how to alias objects/qualify columns (most of my code was lifted from a previous member of the team.  Would be really grateful if someone could give me some sample code to work around my query/ies?

Comment: @JamesDavis I explain how to alias in the linked article.

Comment: Thanks @Larnu, that makes sense.  Any thoughts/suggestions on any of the queries I had?  Thank you again.

Comment: A lot of what you're doing in SQL code here (including things like getting a totals row and formatting values) is best done on the client side, through things like Excel (possibly combined with Power Query). SQL doesn't work very well as a general reporting tool; you'll be banging your head against things a lot. Having said that, look into things like `GROUP BY GROUPING SETS` and windowed aggregates (`SUM() OVER (PARTITION BY...)`) to get running and grand totals.

Comment: Some (most? all?) of your outer join attempts are defeated by the use of unpreserved table columns in the where clause. And some of the outer joins just seem like overkill due to inexperience or lack of schema knowledge. I also suggest you restructure (at a minimum) the code to match the joins with their associated ON conditions. It **very** difficult to read and understand the query (esp. without useful aliases).

Comment: `C_PERIOD) IN ('2021%')` would likely be better expressed as `C_PERIOD between 202101 and 202112` - assuming that column is numeric. Do NOT rely on implicit conversion. I would expect (and prefer) that a "period" is separated into 2 columns - year and month - to support easier comparison and searching.

Comment: Thank you all.  The coding is mostly borrowed by previous chap, and I am not a SQL coder (as you have all "Picked up on" !).....thanks @SMor for the between statement, I'll give that a shot.  In terms of doing the processing on the client side, unfortunately, the data is being fed into our "inflexible" ERP system, so it's pretty much a "single query" to present the data in a table........so, I do appreciate the comments that it SHOULD be formatted, etc., on the client side, but unfortunately not possible in this situation.....  I'll take a look into GROUP BY, etc., thank you Jeroen.